# Is it possible to get byte[] from FileResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arrays, fileresult

Is it possible to get `byte[]` from `FileResult` in C#?

Comment: If you need the file bytes why not just read the file directly? `FileResult` is the wrong type to use.

Comment: @asawyer Well I don't have access to that functionality. I have access to get FileResult only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx) is an `abstract` class so that won't be the underlying *instance* type - assuming the correct [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460208(v=vs.118).aspx) is used then you should be able to cast it to a [FileContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

```cs
if (result is FileContentResult data)
{
    var content = data.FileContents;
}
```

Comment: FWIW for the sake of code clarity, i think an explicit cast would be preferred in this situation as you'd prefer an `InvalidCastException` over a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'd like think neither would be preferred :)

Comment: *FileContents instead